# Populate treeview from table data and integrating checkbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to create a treeview from a data table with checkboxes that will display some information in a table to the right based on the same data table. I have made a simple example below.

[image]

Comment: good on You :) what is the question?

Comment: Hehe, I was interested in knowing how to do this in C#.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It is a pretty big implementation to do for you from scratch, cant be bothered TBH but i can point to some nice article on working with treeviews https://www.codeproject.com/Tags/Treeview and in wpf datagrids https://www.codeproject.com/Tags/datagrid 

but if this is your business i think this is the case where you need to learn to fish and not get a herring so to say ;)

Comment: Cool. thanks, I'll check it out  !